# Set static IP for Ubuntu mini 17.10

Tags: ethernet, ubuntu-minimal, static-ip

I am trying to configure ethernet, for my PC, with static IP/Gateway/Nameservers.

I edited `/etc/network/interfaces`, `/etc/systemd/network/*.network`, `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` but none of these files give the result I need for a static IP.

So, what else?

In Ubuntu mini, who configures the ethernet?

`ifconfig` gives (before changes to configuration files):

```
enp0s4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::210:5cff:fee9:a3b1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:10:5c:e9:a3:b1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 100  bytes 18369 (18.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 125  bytes 16802 (16.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 50  bytes 3276 (3.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 50  bytes 3276 (3.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`ps aux | grep network` gives:

```
systemd+   237  0.0  0.8  18680  4116 ?        Ss   00:49   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
# ....
# ....unrelated loopback lines
# ....
auto enp0s4
iface enp0s4 inet static
address 192.168.1.11/24
gateway 192.168.1.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 192.9.43.50 192.9.43.51
```

`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s4:
        addresses: 192.168.1.11/24
        dhcp4: no
        gateway4: 192.168.1.4
        nameservers:
          addresses: [192.9.43.50, 192.9.43.51]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `ifconfig` and also: `ps aux | grep etwork`

Comment: I'm not 100% positive on this one, but maybe try removing the `/24` off the IP address when you're using the netmask line as `255.255.255.0` and `/24` mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of `man systemd.network` reading, I came to the following workaround:

rename file `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp0s4.network` to something without `.network` extension.

create file `/etc/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp0s4.network` with the following contents:

```
[Match]
Name=enp0s4

[Network]
DHCP=no
DNS=192.9.43.50
DNS=192.9.43.51
Address=192.168.1.11/24
Gateway=192.168.1.4
Domain=domain.domain
```